# How to disable vmwgfx driver without compiling a new kernel on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux-kernel, driver, linux-device-driver, ubuntu-16.04

I know I can disable it by compiling a new kernel without setting CONFIG_DRM_VMWGFX in `config` file. But I don't want build a new kernel, can I achieve it by modify some configurations?

I tried to delete `vmwgfx.ko` from the `lib/modules/XXX/kernel/driver` directory, then reboot, but the driver works well On Ubuntu 16.04. Why? Is the file elsewhere?

And I also tried to rmmod,but it's not work.

```
[root@ubuntu:] lsmod |grep vmwgfx
vmwgfx                235405  4 
drm_kms_helper        159169  1 vmwgfx
ttm                    99345  1 vmwgfx
drm                   370825  7 ttm,drm_kms_helper,vmwgfx
[root@ubuntu:] rmmod -f vmwgfx
rmmod: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:793 kmod_module_remove_module()
could not remove 'vmwgfx': Resource temporarily unavailable
[root@ubuntu:] modprobe -r vmwgfx
modprobe: FATAL: Module vmwgfx is in use.
```

Comment: Depending on what kind of module it is, you might be able to use `rmmod ` <module name>.  Use `lsmod` to see a listing.

Comment: Phrase `Module vmwgfx is in use.` doesn't mean that vmwgfx is *built-in*. As opposite, it means that `vmwgfx` is a **module**. You may type `lsmod` to see list of modules. In this list you may also see which module uses your one. BTW, the question is not about programming at all, so it is **off-topic** on Stack Overflow. You may ask it on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: You can blacklist modules in the modprobe configuration to stop them being loaded automatically. See [modprobe.d(5)](https://linux.die.net/man/5/modprobe.d).

Comment: @askubuntu A module can also be in use without some other module using it, for example when something opens a device managed by the module, its "in-use" count will go up. Since `vmwgfx` is a graphics driver, there are probably Xorg servers and frame-buffer console tty processes (e.g. `agetty`) using it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, I know how to do it.

The reason for my situation is that the driver's file is stored in initramfs-xxx.img. So we need to rebuild a initramfs-xxx.img.

0. find file path: `modinfo vmwgfx`

```
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/vmwgfx/vmwgfx.ko
version:        2.9.0.0
license:        GPL and additional rights
description:    Standalone drm driver for the VMware SVGA device
author:         VMware Inc. and others
srcversion:     AC179B70460E5C5D32AC416
alias:          pci:v000015ADd00000405sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        ttm,drm,drm_kms_helper
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-21-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           enable_fbdev:Enable vmwgfx fbdev (int)
parm:           force_dma_api:Force using the DMA API for TTM pages (int)
parm:           restrict_iommu:Try to limit IOMMU usage for TTM pages (int)
parm:           force_coherent:Force coherent TTM pages (int)
parm:           restrict_dma_mask:Restrict DMA mask to 44 bits with IOMMU (int)
```

1. remove the driver file `mv /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/driver/gpu/drm/vmwgfx/vmwgfx.ko /home/$(whoami)/`.
2. backup your boot img: `` mv /boot/initrd.img-`uname -r` /home/`whoami`/ ``
3. rebuld boot img: `` mkinitrd -f /boot/initrd.img-`uname -r` `uname -r` ``
4. reboot

If you want to remove other build-in driver file, this method works well.
If your vm is centos, just choose the correct file path and boot img name.

Comment: What do you mean by `uname` here?

Comment: @Deniel it means I should replace current kernel's boot file.